# Elixir: Difference between require and import

Tags: import, elixir, require

What is the difference between require and import?

```
iex> require Integer
Integer
iex> Integer.is_odd(3)
true
```

and

```
iex> import List, only: [duplicate: 2]
List
iex> duplicate :ok, 3
[:ok, :ok, :ok]
```

It seems that they both do the same thing... get macros or functions from other modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html):

> We use import whenever we want to easily access functions or macros from other modules **without using the fully-qualified name**.

also

> Note that `importing` a module automatically `requires` it.

So if you `import Integer`, you can directly call `is_odd`, you don't need `Integer.is_odd`

Answer (score 2):

## require

According to this [article](https://curiosum.dev/blog/alias-import-require-use-in-elixir):

> Macro function is being evaluated during compilation. If you want to use it, you need to compile it first. This is exactly what `require` does.

In the background, it also gives an alias to required module, which means that you can pass `as` option just like with `alias`:

```
require TestModule, as: Test
```

## import

The import directive allows you to skip the module part by importing all or some of the functions/macros:

```
import IO, only: [puts: 1]

puts "Hello"
```

As already mentioned, it also calls `require` in the background to compile it first.